# Set div's left value based on grandparent element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have an absolute div nested inside a relative div.  I want the absolute div's left value to be relative to the grandparent's position, but still allow it's height to be relative to it's parent element.  Here is where the page is: http://pixeloft.com/clients/supportcenter/facilitators/

I want the left value of the bio element to always have the left value of the first "Frank Abdale" on click.

Is this possible by setting the div's left value through js?

Here is my code: http://jsfiddle.net/6RQ3u/

HTML:

```
    <div class="person">
    <div class="person-info">   <a class="showBio" target="1">
    <h4>Name 1</h4></a>

        <div class="arrow" id="arrow-1">^</div>
    </div>
    <div class="bio-wrapper">
        <div class="bio" id="bio-box-1"><a class="hideBio" target="1">X</a>Bio</div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="person">
    <div class="person-info">   <a class="showBio" target="2">
    <h4>Name 2</h4></a>

        <div class="arrow" id="arrow-2">^</div>
    </div>
    <div class="bio-wrapper">
        <div class="bio" id="bio-box-2"><a class="hideBio" target="2">X</a>Bio</div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="person">
    <div class="person-info">   <a class="showBio" target="3">
    <h4>Name 3</h4></a>

        <div class="arrow" id="arrow-3">^</div>
    </div>
    <div class="bio-wrapper">
        <div class="bio" id="bio-box-3"><a class="hideBio" target="3">X</a>Bio</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.person a h4 {
    color: #000;
    font-weight: normal;
    font-size: 18px;
    line-height: 21px;
    width: 100px;
}
.bio {
    border-top: 18px solid #387496;
    position:absolute;
    width:618px!important;
    float:left;
    background-color:#d8edf4;
    padding:15px 170px;
    top:284px;
    left:-19px;
    display:none;
    z-index:200;
    clear: both;
}
.person {
    width:164px;
    margin-right:20px;
    float:left;
    display:inline;
    margin-bottom:30px;
    position: relative;
}
.person-info {
    float:left;
}
.showBio {
    float:left;
}
.hideBio {
    float:right;
    color:#fff!important;
    font-size:11px;
    position: absolute;
    right: 10px;
    top: -14px;
}
.arrow {
    display:none;
    background: url('images/bio-arrow.jpg') no-repeat -2px -6px #fff;
    float: left;
    display: block;
    clear: both;
    width: 30px;
    height: 15px;
    text-indent: -3000px;
}
a{cursor:pointer;}
```

JQuery:

```
jQuery(function () {
    jQuery('.bio').hide();
    jQuery('.arrow').hide();
    jQuery('.showBio').click(function () {
        jQuery('.bio').hide();
        jQuery('.arrow').hide();
        jQuery('#bio-box-' + $(this).attr('target')).slideToggle('fast');
        jQuery('#arrow-' + $(this).attr('target')).slideToggle('fast');
    });
    jQuery('.hideBio').click(function () {
        jQuery('#bio-box-' + $(this).attr('target')).slideToggle('slow');
        jQuery('#arrow-' + $(this).attr('target')).slideUp();
    });

});
```

Thanks for all your help!

Comment: Include `markup` in your question.

Comment: What do you mean by *left value*

Comment: can you be a little more specific what div you are talking about? there are two bio elements (the bio wrapper and then the showBio. I also can't find the div that has position set as absolute.

Comment: by "left value" I'm referring to the CSS left value.  I want the div "bio" to always have the same left value in relation to the div wrapping the person div.  Does that make more sense?